# How to edit mobile CSS in SocialEngine?

Tags: php, css, socialengine

I can't find a way to edit the mobile CSS for **SocialEngine 4.2.3** (I had the file `mobile.css` in `application/themes/default` when I installed). I can't find it in **Layout -> Theme Editor**.

**edit** Forgot to add, for those who don't know, if I edit the file myself with an IDE, it doesn't update in SocialEngine's pages.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mobile.css is not available for edit in the Theme Editor. You can edit the mobile.css in {site root}/application/themes/{your current theme}/mobile.css. Keep in mind that that different modules also have their own CSS. They are usually located in {site root}/application/modules/{the module whose CSS you'd like to edit}/externals/styles/mobile.css.